# Login by vkontakte in ASP MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, vk

I use ASP MVC5, AspNet.Identity. A want to login in to my site using vkontakte oAuth.

What I have done:

1) Create Vkontakte App type - "web site", Open API - turn on, Adress of site:  `http://localhost:1729`; Base domain : `localhost`; trusted redirect URI: `-` left blank, because tried different variants and always gives an error;

2) Install nuget Owin.Security.Providers.VKontakte (https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders)

3) In Startup.Auth.cs set:
`app.UseVKontakteAuthentication("372323899", "vdQOYlASDfsagNhBr0vOAUX");`

4) Press button (screenshot http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/11/19/0000/0020/4116/16/c154eb2154.png)  and Nothing happens. In browser console - http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/11/19/0000/0020/4116/16/b178c9e29b.png

Where have I mistaken? Why does not it redirect to the page vkontakte for granting access to my application?

Comment: What do you have in browser Network tab? Do you see the request?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I see  error acess_denied - http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/11/22/0000/0020/4116/16/f3775a6e14.png

Comment: Are they all redirects or you have an auth dialog? If you rejected it previously, it can lead to redirects.

Comment: No, not any redirects or auth dialog. I never rejected it.... I public site on hosting - https://legends-vamp.tk/Account/Login  and now error. I will setup exception thise error for detailed view

Comment: All works fine, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that.